# Selecting nonzero values from a large sparse R matrix,

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have a very large sparse matrix in R. For specified rows, I want to get out only the nonzero values from the respective columns (typically 5-10 out of 10000). Using the View option, only a very small subset of the matrix can be visualized (exceeds memory, I guess). I get the same problem, when I use e.g. A[1, ] to get out the first row of A..
I would like to get a vector containing only the column indices and corresponding values, where the value is above zero, whenever I specify a specific row of the matrix. Is there a smart way of doing this?

Comment: `which(A[i,]!>0)` will tell you which the positions of columns for the i-th row with a value over 0.

Comment: Thanks, it works, when ! is left out, otherwise I got an error. Any smart way of getting the combined values for columns and matrix entry out also instead of calling them individually?

Comment: I'm sorry. I tried to write `which(A[i,]>0)` or `which(A[i,]!=0)` which means different from 0.

Comment: If your matrix is sparse, use a sparse matrix to store it; this structure automatically stores the column and row indices of non-zero terms. It is easy to subset these to get  > 0 terms.

Comment: Yes, I actually tried converting to a sparse dgcMatrix earlier, but I could not get the data out. Could you specify how you would do it given a sparse matrix - I need both the column indices and the corresponding matrix value

Comment: @Crusader ; example data :`m = matrix(sample(0:3, 100, prob=c(10,1,1, 1), replace=TRUE), 10)` . convert to sparse `library(Matrix) ; m2 = as(m, "TsparseMatrix")` . Have a look at object `str(m2)` . You can extract column (`j`) `m2@j+1` . One is added as indexing starts at zero in sparse matrices. The values are stored in `x`. `m2@x` . [btw: sorry i didnt see you message -  users are notified if you add @username (ie @user2957945) to your message ]

Comment: @user2957945, thank you, very useful :-)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a sparse dgCMatrix and the user-selected row is in variable 'rowIndx', the following code will create an index of all non-zero values and then pick user-selected row of interest from that.

```
rowIndx <- 2
mm <- Matrix::Matrix(matrix(rbinom(2e4, 1, 0.10), ncol = 100))
```

Create the indices of non-zero elements

```
colN <- diff(mm@p) #get the number of non-zero elements in each column
indx <- cbind(mm@i+1,rep(seq_along(colN),colN)) #create the indices of all non-zero elements
```

Get the required column indices and values

```
indx[which(indx[,1]==rowIndx),2] #vector of non-zero column indices
mm[rowIndx,indx[which(indx[,1]==rowIndx),2]] #vector of non-zero values
```

This method is three times faster than creating indices with 'which'

```
indx <- which(mm!=0,arr.ind = T)
```

method for large dgCMatrix with 2e8 elements.